# JS - setAttribute (a function with 2 parameters) to a bidimensional array

Tags: javascript, foreach, parameters

I'm trying to make a mini-calculator for my form. My html-form is based on data-prototype, so it renders an unlimited amount of forms with 2 inputs : date and duration.
This inputs are rendered with ID-s like `loan_charge_0_date` , `loan_charge_1_duration` ; next one : `loan_charge_1_date`, loan_charge_1_duration` and so on.

I already wrote a code that with regex creates an array with all `ids` of date, and an another array with all `ids` of durations. So, when I click on `+` button that adds a new form, my `dateIdsArray = [loan_charge_0_date]` and `durationIdArray = [loan_charge_0_duration]`. When I click it again, it pushed one more element to each array, the `loan_charge_1_date in dateIdsArray` and `loan_charge_1_duration` to durationIdsArray`.

Now, I need to each pair (form) to bind a function with 2 parameters like date.value and duration.value ... and in this function to make my `endingDateCalculator`.

In this order, I made some easy statements that first...concat this 2 arrays, and after that make them as a pair ... so, result array is a bidimensional array :

```
pairValuesArray = [
[loan_charge_0_date, loan_charge_0_duration],
[loan_charge_1_date, loan_charge_1_duration],
[loan_charge_2_date, loan_charge_2_duration]
];
```

How can I append an function to every this pair, so when I `onkeyup` the duration of input, it will call the `endingDateCalculator` function with 2 parameters (this.date, this.duration) and perform calculations?

I tried smth like :

```
pairArray.forEach( x => document.getElementById(x).setAttribute('onkeyup', 'endingDateCalculator(this.value, this.value);'));
```

but it show me ... can not run setAttribute to a null :/

My entire script is here :

```
<script>
var bodyText =  document.getElementsByClassName('panel-group')[0].innerHTML;
var durationIds = bodyText.match(/id="(.*duration)"/g);
var durationIdArray = durationIds.map(y => y = y.split('\"')[1]);

var dateIds = bodyText.match(/id="(.*date)"/g);
var dateIdArray = dateIds.map(x => x = x.split('\"')[1]);

var concatArray = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < durationIds.length; i++) {
    concatArray.push(dateIdArray[i]);
    concatArray.push(durationIdArray[i]);
}

var pairArray = new Array ();

var i,j,temparray,chunk = 2;
for (i=0,j=concatArray.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    temparray = concatArray.slice(i,i+chunk);
    pairArray.push(temparray);    
}

console.debug(pairArray);
pairArray.forEach( x => document.getElementById(x).setAttribute('onkeyup', 'endingDateCalculator(this.value, this.value);'));
//dateIdArray.forEach( x => document.getElementById(x).setAttribute('onkeyup', 'endingDateCalculator(this.value);'));

function endingDateCalculator(valueOfDate, valueOfDuration) {
    alert(valueOfDate + valueOfDuration);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you send the output of your `console.debug(pairArray)` for me?

Comment: @SamHH 
If I had 2 forms, the pairArray looks like : 
`   
[Array(2), Array(2)]
[0]Array(2)
0 : "loan_charges_0_date"
1 : "loan_charges_0_duration"

[1]:Array(2)
[0] : "loan_charges_1_date"
[1] : "loan_charges_1_duration"
 `

Comment: And what are the IDs in the DOM you're expecting to target?

Comment: my  pairArray that I outputed above, contains sub-arrays of pair-values, each pair is a combination of id of particular date and same duration, for example combination  loan_charges_0_date and loan_charges_0_duration.
I need to bind an function with 2 arguments to each that pair. And argument to be a value of loan_charges_0_date and loan_charges_0_duration.  

So, in other words, I expect in my form, first to introduce the date... for example 28/02/2017, and when introducing duration, onkeyup to run the function that will add to this date N amounts of months and output the ending date.

Comment: I mean, what is the ID of the DOM element you want to `setAttribute` to? In HTML terms, is it just one element or is there one corresponding element for each of those IDs e.g. `<el id="loan_charges_0_date">`?

Comment: When I press + (render one more form) it generates me a div with 2 inputs

<input type="text" id="loan_charges_1_date" name="loan[charges][1][date]" class="form-control" value="01/01/2001" onkeyup="alert(this.value);">
<input type="text" id="loan_charges_1_duration" name="loan[charges][1][duration]" class="form-control" value="24">

When I press + again, it generate me the same structure, just instead of number 1 is 2, and so on.
So, on each this mini-form, I want first to introduce date, and onkeyup at duration to bind a function with parameters of date.value an duration.value

Comment: Okay. Well, first thing to do is fix your `forEach`. Try this and see if your script gets any further (sorry for formatting, comments not good for this):

`pairArray.forEach(pair => pair.forEach(id => {
  const el = document.getElementById(id)

  if (!el) {
    console.log(\`Could not find id ${id}.\`)

    return
  }

  el.setAttribute('onkeyup', 'endingDateCalculator(this.value, this.value);')
}));`

Comment: Tell you what, if you'd like, to save us both time, if you can put the prerequisite HTML and JS into say JSFiddle I'll solve it for you. Hard to understand as-is :-)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7L5rv1mw/
You can see 3 lines after charges. Line 1 is already created and saved, 2 as well, but an unnumbered line is generated by date-prototype. So it has a random ID, in this case -> 151.
All line has inputs with id 151.
So, at generated line, I need to record the value of introduced date, and when I introduce duration, onkeyup to run the function with values of this 2 inputs..perform some calculations and return the value anywhere

Comment: Sorry for a lot of unnecessary HTML. I edited it, now just all necessary information is there.
https://jsfiddle.net/7L5rv1mw/2/

Comment: Hey, bro. I tried this script :
pairArray.forEach(pair => pair.forEach(id => { const el = document.getElementById(id);  return el.setAttribute('onkeyup', 'endingDateCalculator();') }));
and it's working, i just need to pass to this function value of data and of duration as parameters, how can I do it ?
and inside function for now to make a console.log of each value

Comment: Is this what you had in mind? (check browser console) https://jsfiddle.net/SamHH/x2j72xou/

Comment: Yep, bro. Smth like that. I'm just not so good in JS, so I don't understand everything in ur code. I just need this values to be passed in a function, and just to make a dummy check with an alert if when I introduce smth in duration (onKeyUp) input, it calls function with value of date and value of duration. Then, this 2 values are passed in function, and just output them, to be sure that I have this values inside my function and to can write the code of edit-date and output it somewhere.
Can you please finish this idea?

Comment: Oh..and smth else, when i generate a new form, script is no working... console said me : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'getValuesFromArrOfEl' has already been declared"

Comment: Aww, so sorry. My bad. I don't observe everything. So, in console.log everything works. But second problem I solved just changing all const to var.
Now...just cause I don't know all this syntax of ur code... can u say me please, how to every generated form, below the duration input, to put a "CSS tooltip" in which endingDate will be inserted as result of endingDateCalculator() function  ?

P.S. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Hold up, don't change stuff from `const` to `var`. How are you including that script in your page? Sounds like you're including it more than once. This could cause issues.

Comment: I put this script in my prototype, so for every generated-form it generates this script as well. It seems that i checked...so, when I generate 2-3 forms and introduce in different inputs...it works for every pair apart...
How can i do this thing with tooltip...?)
Can you give me ur skype or smth to send u files from my prototype ... u better to understand how it is structurated and where to put the html to achieve my goal?
Thank you.

Comment: That's not really the "right" way to do this. You need to include that script _once_. When you want to create more HTML don't do it as a big block in a HTML data attribute, instead create a JS script to do it properly. It would make everything much, much easier to work with.

Comment: I know, bro. I will try to include it just once, may be it will work fine.
How can I append an paragraph to duration input, so..after my calculations in endingDateCalculator() value will be inner.html in this paragraph?
Now I have 
var endingDateCalculator = (durationValue, dateValue) => {
    durationValue = Number(durationValue);
    document.getElementById("loan_charges_151_value").innerHTML = durationValue;
}

But it's not a solution. I need script to detect the curent input duration id, and below it, to append a paragraph, and in this paragraph to make innerHTML the result

Comment: In that case I would return the value you want in the paragraph from that function and assign that to a value in the anonymous function we called it from. Now in there you have access to both elements in the `pair` argument. Also, unless you're actually using HTML in this value, you should use `textContent` instead.